# How to achieve direct-server-return with HAProxy and app server?

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, haproxy

What would be an example method of achieving DSR with HAProxy and an app server like node.js? I've read a few articles on the subject however I don't quite understand how the node server can respond to the request directly when the client connected to the load balancer first.

...unless there's some lower level, virtual interface proxying going on.

Answer (score 3):

DSR can't be done through HAProxy, since HAProxy is a reverse proxy.
HAProxy acknowledges the client TCP connection then it creates a new TCP connection to the server on which it forwards the request.
The sever can't answer to the client directly, since it is not aware of the client TCP connection.

If you want to achieve DSR mode, you must use LVS, which has a module for this purpose.

Baptiste

Answer (score 2):

I have reason to believe this is possible as the ALOHA appliance from HAProxy Technologies (that runs HAProxy internally) does officially support DSR mode.  However, I still have not figured it out how they do this.

They even have a technical application note about how to set up your backend servers to work with this mode.
See: http://www.haproxy.com/static/media/uploads/eng/resources/aloha_load_balancer_appnotes_0053_server_configuration_for_layer4_dsr_mode_en.pdf

Unfortunately, this document doesn't say anything about how the HAProxy itself is configured.  Still digging!

Answer (score -1):

As explained by Baptiste above haproxy cannot do DSR as its reverse proxy in case of aloha you can disable the reverse proxy mode which in this case uses the LVS feature of linux to work as l4 loadbalancer which can be used for DSR.